# How to get value of nested props function for unit testing

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have an issue with getting value of nested props function.

`this.props.user.getPerson().getData()`

`getPerson` returns new object with person related data.

`getData` returns person related data.

It's separated for readability and I want to make it work for unit testing.

Test 1:

```
 let _wrapper,
    initialProps

  beforeEach(() => {
    initialProps = {
      user: {
        getPerson: () => {}
      }
    }
    _wrapper = shallow(<Test1 {...initialProps} />)
  })
some tests...
})
```

It returned `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getData' of undefined`.

Test2

```
 let _wrapper,
    initialProps

  beforeEach(() => {
    initialProps = {
      user: {
        getPerson: () => { getData: () => {} }
      }
    }
    _wrapper = shallow(<Test2 {...initialProps} />)
  })
some tests...
})
```

It returned `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getData' of undefined`
Same error as Test1.

I tried to get value of props function by passing function however it didn't work from second function.

How can I get value of nested props function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [wrap object literals in parentheses to return them from arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Returning_object_literals):

```
initialProps = {
  user: {
    getPerson: () => ({ getData: () => { } })  // wrap in parentheses
  }
}
```

Comment: @aaayumi awesome, glad it was helpful!